# Angular 4 - webpack: Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

When I try `npm install` everything seems to work fine, but then `ng serve` return error. I was trying almost everything, but nothing works. Maybe there is a problem with versions of angular? The same project is working on another computer. Any suggestions what is wrong?

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/myUser/Desktop/to/Project/frontend/src/index.html' in '/Users/myUser/Desk  top/to/Project/frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs':
  Error: Can't resolve '/Users/myUser/Desktop/to/Project/frontend/src/index.html' in '/Users/myUser/Desktop/to/Project/frontend/node  _modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs'

  - compiler.js:76 
    [frontend]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:291 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:291:10

  - Compiler.js:494 
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:494:13

  - Tapable.js:138 next
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11

  - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

  - Tapable.js:142 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13

  - Compiler.js:491 
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:491:10

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:645 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:645:19

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:636 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:636:11

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:631 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:631:10

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

  - Compilation.js:627 sealPart2
    [frontend]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:627:9

  - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [frontend]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46


webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: can u pls also post ur file structure ?

Comment: Looks like you don't have an `index.html` at the root of your project.

Comment: Yes, it was causing a problem. I added `index.html` to my structure of files and everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> SOLUTION:
>
> **I added `index.html` to my structure of files and everything is working properly.**